# Is there a way to install Toad-for-MySQL on ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I was wondering whether there is a way to install Toad-for-MySQL on ubuntu?

I can't find any appropriate solution.

Can somebody help to solve this issue.

If it isn't possible, is there maybe a good alternative under linux?

Answer (score 0):

This from [here:](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-mysql/f/22/t/21243.aspx)

I was able to install it and now it works perfectly.

Short howto:

> kubuntu 13.10
>
> wine-1.7.11
>
> playonlinux  4.2.1

- create a new "driver" in play on linux in 32bit mode emulating
  windows xp.
- Install dotnet40 inside this driver (you can do it going in the
  configuration options).
- Launch toad for mysql 7.0 installation.

***Now you should have a working Toad.***

I suggest to disable (in toad configuration) all the option that use internet otherwise you get an exception since IE is not installed.